# copying multiple rows in excel and pasting to another sheet

Tags: excel

i have n excel sheet. i want to copy the alternative rows to another excel sheet.
please help me. I tried using ctrl+v, but it prompts :
        That command cannot be used on multiple selections.

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to copy different columns from different rows?

Comment: Make a screenshot and be _very_ specific to the _exact_ steps you are performing. This will make it easier for others to try and help you. Make sure you use `CTRL` when performing the copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy different sections from multiple rows. That sounds like it might be your problem. Select the entire row by clicking the row number to the left and paste it into the other sheet that way, then edit the data as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can't copy non contiguous rows in excel , how would you expect them to paste? Together or separated ?

You can only select non contiguous rows( multiple selections) for formatting etc

Best to use vba to do these kind of copy paste jobs

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, this is incorrect. What do you mean by "non continuous"? I can certainty copy rows 1, 8, 19 (as an example), and paste them into another sheet or workbook without issue. They don't retain the row numbers/position, but they WILL paste in one after the other.